# Programmatically place the Cursor inside a textField of a custom tableView header

Tags: swift, tableview, becomefirstresponder

How can you programmatically make sure that the cursor of a tableView-HeaderView-TextField gets active (i.e. is the first responder) ??

My table looks like this (i.e with the custom TextField header). So far, the cursor only gets inside the grey header field by clicking inside the textfield. But I would like to be able to get the cursor inside the textfield programmatically....

[image]

The code for my custom tableview-header looks like this :

```
// drawing a custom Header-View with a TextField on top of the tableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50))
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, 15, self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 40, 45))
    textField.delegate = self
    self.txtfield = textField
    textField.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    let placeholder = NSAttributedString(string: "..add player", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.darkGrayColor()])
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = placeholder
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    container.addSubview(textField)

    var headPlusBttn:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as! UIButton
    headPlusBttn.center.x = self.view.frame.size.width - 20
    headPlusBttn.center.y = 38
    headPlusBttn.enabled = true
    headPlusBttn.addTarget(self, action: "addTeam:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    container.addSubview(headPlusBttn)

    return container
}
```

My first approach was to set the first-responder of the headerViewForSection like this (see code):

```
// reload entries
func reloadEntries() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    // the following does unfortunately not work !!!!!
    self.tableView.headerViewForSection(1)?.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Not sure why this does not work. Maybe, the Section-Nr (Int=1) is wrong. But I tried several section-numbers. No curser where it should be.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Usually adding a delay helps in situations like this. It allows the OS to do everything it wants with the view, and then it won't mess up what you're trying to do at the same time.

Maybe something like this:

```
func reloadEntries() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    let delay = (Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC) * 0.1)
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, triggerTime), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.headerViewForSection(1)?.becomeFirstResponder()
    })
}
```

I haven't tested this to do what you want, so you may need to find a different place to put this.

Also, are you sure you want to affect the view in section 1? From your image it looks like you want to mess with the header in section 0.

Be sure to drop into the debugger and check that the header isn't nil. Your code implies that that's a valid condition. You might try writing it like this (at least for testing):

```
if let header = self.tableView.headerViewForSection(1) {
    header.becomeFirstResponder()
}
else {
    print("There is no header.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
    self.tableView.headerViewForSection(1)?.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()